# Upload specific Chef cookbook version with knife?

Tags: chef, knife

Is it possible to upload an exact version of a Chef cookbook via knife? All I've seen is that knife will upload the latest version it can find.

Is it possible to upload a specific version? Downloading examples show:

```
$ knife cookbook download COOKBOOK_NAME [COOKBOOK_VERSION] (options)
```

Is there a way to do this with the upload command?

Comment: You set the version in metadata.rb. See https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_metadata.html

Comment: I actually have multiple versions of a single cookbook that do have different metadata versions, I was just hoping to upload a specific version I have that could be in one of my cookbook_path directories from knife.

Answer (score 1):

Knife upload te version of code you have on your disk, on the corresponding *cookbook-dir* inside your cookbooks path,  that is configured on your **knife.rb**

That being said,  if you use tags on your cookbooks,  you can use git to do checkouts and switch to the desired version.  Then invoke the:

```
knife upload COOKBOOK_NAME
```